# Loading images from drawable folder into your app using glide

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-glide

I would like to load images into my RecyclerView so that I can view them on a grid list using `Glide` but the images are in my drawable folder. I have tried it but my app is crashing when I test it. 
Here's my code snippet.
The adapter

```
    List<Graphic_list> glist;
    Context gcontext;
    public Graphics_adapter(Context context,List<Graphic_list> list){
        gcontext=context;
        glist=list;
    }
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        Context context=parent.getContext();
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        View gview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_thumbnail,parent,false);
        ViewHolder gholder=new ViewHolder(gview);
        return gholder;
    }
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Graphic_list graphiclist=glist.get(position);
        Glide.with(gcontext).load(graphiclist.getImagegraphic()).thumbnail(0.5f).crossFade().into(holder.graphicimage);
    }
```

my view holder class

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView graphicimage;
        public ViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);
            graphicimage=(ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cardimage);
            }
    }
```

Get data method

```
public static List<Graphic_list> getData() {
        ArrayList<Graphic_list> glist = new ArrayList<>();
        int[] image = {R.drawable.pencil_ic, R.drawable.pencil_ic, R.drawable.pencil_ic, R.drawable.pencil_ic};

        for (int i = 0; i < image.length ; i++) {
            Graphic_list graphic_list = new Graphic_list();
            graphic_list.imagegraphic = image[i];
            glist.add(graphic_list);
        }
```

And my Fragment that houses my recyclerView

```
 public class Graphic extends Fragment {
ArrayList<Graphic_list> grlist=(ArrayList<Graphic_list>)Graphic_list.getData();
RecyclerView graphicrv;
RecyclerView.LayoutManager gridm;
    @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Inflate the layout for this fragment
            View graphiclayout=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_graphic, container, false);
            graphicrv= (RecyclerView) graphiclayout.findViewById(R.id.rvgraphic);
            Graphics_adapter graphics_adapter=new Graphics_adapter(getActivity(),grlist);
            graphicrv.setAdapter(graphics_adapter);
            gridm=new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),2);
            graphicrv.setLayoutManager(gridm);
            return graphiclayout;
        }
```

The log Cat Error message

```
    08-19 12:30:03.380 13446-13446/ke.co.clickaway.squirrel.clickawaytechnologies 
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                               Process: ke.co.clickaway.squirrel.clickawaytechnologies, PID: 13446
                                                                                                    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View
                                                                                                        at com.bumptech.glide.GenericRequestBuilder.into(GenericRequestBuilder.java:678)
                                                                                                        at com.bumptech.glide.DrawableRequestBuilder.into(DrawableRequestBuilder.java:448)
                                                                                                        at ke.co.clickaway.squirrel.clickawaytechnologies.Adapters.Graphics_adapter.onBindViewHolder(Graphics_adapter.java:40)
                                                                                                        at ke.co.clickaway.squirrel.clickawaytechnologies.Adapters.Graphics_adapter.onBindViewHolder(Graphics_adapter.java:21)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5471)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:5504)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4741)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:4617)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:1994)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.layoutChunk(GridLayoutManager.java:528)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1353)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:574)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(GridLayoutManager.java:170)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3028)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:2906)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3283)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:1055)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onLayout(ViewPager.java:1695)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
                                                                                                        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
                                                                                                        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14981)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4790)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1998)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1753)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
                                                                                                        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
                                                                                                        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
                                                                                                        at a
    08-19 12:30:03.901 612-13757/? E/android.os.Debug: !@Dumpstate > sdumpstate -k -t -z -d -m 13446 -o /data/log/dumpstate_app_error
    08-19 12:30:04.411 13477-13497/? E/IntentOperationSvc: Failed to instantiate Chimera operation impl, dropping operation
```

Comment: Please provided the logcat with the exception

Comment: Sorry for the delay i just added the logcat message.